# Что нужно/знать уметь на Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Понимаю, что вопрос довольной субъективной, но где у вас была та самая черта, после которой вы могли сказать "пора искать работу".

Допустим, я "изучил" spring mvc, data, rest, что-то могу написать, несколькими способами настроить, но у меня нет представления о том что нужно для реальной работы, достаточно ли тех знаний, которые уже есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для реальной работы в первую очередь нужно понимание того, как это работает, что и почему происходит под капотом. Свести к минимуму *магию* Spring. На деле можно вести какой-то учебный проект, и по ходу находить, что ещё нужно для более полного понимания.

Абсолютной точки, после которой вас возьмут на работу, конечно же нет. В первую очередь будет влиять ваш общий технический бэкграунд. А в целом - всё по желанию работодателя.